# Breezejs with a dataform

Tags: javascript, html, breeze, dataform, devforce

We are getting ready to move our app over from Silverlight to HTML5/Javascript. In Silverlight we were using Devforce and Cocktail.

We also relied heavily on Silverlight's dataform for editing records. We had created a generic screen that could take just about any of our entities and make its fields editable.

Breeze has handled the Devforce aspect of our code but we are struggling to find an answer for the dataform. We dont want to create a bunch of different screens just to edit records. We are looking for a way to generate most of the view based off of the entities we receive from Breeze.

Anybody doing this? Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For **inspiration**, you might spelunk the as-yet-undocumented-unreleased [Breeze Inspector in the Breeze Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/tree/master/Samples/Breeze.Inspector). This app creates HTML "forms" dynamically, choosing controls for each property and laying them out based on its own metadata. It uses some "advanced" techniques involving RequireJs. It's offered "as is"; please don't expect support for it. I think it is simple and clever (in a good sense) and hope to shape it into something publishable.